# If $f$ is Riemann integrable over $\alpha$, then $f$ is Riemann integrable over $V$

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose that $\alpha \in BV[a,b]$ and $V(x)$ is its total variation function on $[a,b]$.Show that if $f\in R(\alpha)$,then $\mid f \mid \in R(V)$.

What I know so far is if $\alpha \in BV[a,b]$,then $\alpha=\alpha_1 - \alpha_2$.$\alpha_1$ and $\alpha_2$ are both increasing.Since $f \in R(\alpha)$,then,$f \in R(\alpha_1 + \alpha_2)$.My next step would be showing $V\leq\alpha_1+\alpha_2$.Is my idea correct?Can someone help me finish the rest part of proof?

Comment: Who is Remiann?

Comment: Bad idea to use both $\alpha$ and $a$ in a question. Anyway, $\alpha$ is a function – what does it mean for $f$ to be integrable over the function $\alpha$? And what does it mean to be integrable over $V$?

Comment: You should first prove that $f\in R(V) $. This proof is difficult and long and available at https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2592615/72031 Further since $V$ is increasing we have the implication $f\in R(V) \implies |f|\in R(V) $ via triangle inequality $||p|-|q||\leq |p-q|$.

Comment: @Paramanand Singh    Thank you!

Comment: @Paramanand Singh:I checked your link.While in the last step,he considered two subintervals where $g$ is increasing or decreasing.But it seems like he only considered where $g$ is increasing in the following proof.

Comment: Also see https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2033164/72031